# If you connect two libraries, then debugging does not work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I add two class libraries to the "solution".
I am running debugging.
Chrome starts up.
In Chrome, the start page `\Home\Index.cshtml` appears.
After `~10` seconds, debugging automatically stops.
 
**Description.**
I created a project - `WebApplCore`;
I added a class library to the solution - `Models`;
I added a class library to the solution - `DBRepository`.

Project `WebApplCore` - ASP.NET Core;
Class Library `Models`, `DBRepository` - Net.Standard 2.0.

**Conditional notations for "tests":**
- "+" - `project` is included in the `decision`.
- "-" - `project` is not included in the `decision`.

**Test 1.**
  WebApplCore - "+";
  Models - "+";
  DBRepository - "-".
**Result:** debugging works stably. Turning off debugging does not occur.

**Test 2.**
  WebApplCore - "+".
  Models - "-".
  DBRepository - "+".
  **Result:** debugging works stably. Turning off debugging does not occur.

[image]

**Picture-1**
  [image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

**Picture-3**
[image]

**Picture-4**
[image]

**Picture-5**
[image: Picture-5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working demo which shows the user list in web app project by adding reference of class libraries:

*1.Models class library*

1)project structure

[image]

2)User model

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int  Age { get; set; }
}
```

*2.DBRepository class library*

1)project structure

[image]

2)DbContext, refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) for more details about EF Core

```
public class MyDbContext:DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options):base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=WebAppCore;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");

        }
    }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

*3.WebAPPCore*

1)project structure

[image]

2)Index view

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.User>

<table class="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            <a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-accountidvalue="@item.Id">LinkDetails</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
 </tbody>
</table>
```

3)HomeController

```
using DBRepository;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _context.User.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
 }
```

4)Startup.cs , register the DbContext in `ConfigureServices` method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=WebAppCore;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

5)Use the following command in `Package Manager Console`

```
PM> add-migration Initial  //create a migration
PM> update-database        //apply the migration to the database to create the schema
```

**Note:**  Change your target project to the migrations project(`DBRepository`) by using the Package Manager Console's **Default project** drop-down list.

This is my [demo link](https://github.com/SherryCXL/WebAppWithClassLibrary/tree/master), you could refer to.

Comment: Could you place the project in another place I can not download.

Comment: @climivin ,I have updated the demo link which is posted to github, you could check.